Raspberry Pi Pico W(MicroPython) からDiscordに日本語を含むメッセージを送るとエラーが発生する
Raspberry Pi Pico WからDiscordにDMを送信するMicroPythonコードを作成しました。
Discord.pyなどは使用せず、REST APIと直接通信するように実装しています。
import urequests, ujson

#Wi-Fi接続の処理は省略

DataObj = {
 "content": "Hello, World"
}

Header = {
 "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
 "authorization": "Bot <token>"
}

Req = urequests.post("https://discord.com/api/v10/channels/<channel.id>/messages", data=ujson.dumps(DataObj), headers=Header)
print(Req.status) # 200 OK
Req.close()

上記のコードで実行すると問題無くDMを送信することができます。しかしcontentに日本語（正しくはマルチバイト文字）を含めると The request body contains invalid JSON が返されてメッセージが送信できません。つまり日本語のDMが送信できない状態です。
import urequests, ujson

#Wi-Fi接続の処理は省略

DataObj = {
 "content": "こんにちは、世界"
}

Header = {
 "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
 "authorization": "Bot <token>"
}

Req = urequests.post("https://discord.com/api/v10/channels/<channel.id>/messages", data=ujson.dumps(DataObj), headers=Header)
print(Req.text) # {"message": "The request body contains invalid JSON.", "code": 50109}
Req.close()

JSONに問題があるとのことですが、以下の方法を試しましたが問題が解決しませんでした。

data="{'content':'こんにちは、世界'}" JSONを直接記入
data="{'content':'\u3053\u3093\u306b\u3061\u306f\u3001\u4e16\u754c'}" Unicodeエスケープ
URLエンコードをして送信（送信はできるが変換されずそのまま表示されてしまう）
VSCodeで実行

解決方法はありますでしょうか？

Windows11 Pro 23H2
Thonny 4.1.4 (Python 3.10.11)
Raspberry Pi Pico W (RPI_PICO_W-20240602-v1.23.0.uf2)



エディターの文字コードはなんですか？ UTF-8 ？

コメントありがとうございます。
エディター(Thonny IDE)上で文字コードを変更・確認する項目が無い為、Python3デフォルトのUTF-8だと考えられます。VS Codeで実行した際はUTF-8の設定になっていました。

JSONを直接記入するのであれば、クオートではなくダブルクオートで記入すべきではないでしょうか?

コメントありがとうございます。

data="{\"content\":\"こんにちは、世界\"}"
data='{"content": "こんにちは、世界"}'
data='{\'content\': \'こんにちは、世界\'}'

の3通りを試してみました。しかし同じエラーを返されてしまいました。

エディターの文字コードはなんですか？ UTF-8 ？

Thonny IDE上で文字コードを変更・確認する項目が無い為、恐らくPython3デフォルトのUTF-8では無いかと思われます。VS Codeで実行した際は文字コード UTF-8 の記載がありました。

JSONを直接記入するのであれば、クオートではなくダブルクオートで記入すべきではないでしょうか?

@user20098 コメントを元に他3通りの記述方法で試しましたが同じエラーでした。

自己解決しました。
urequests.post で送信されるヘッダーの中身を確認したところ、日本語文字（マルチバイト文字）を1バイトとして計算されており、Content-Lengthの値がバイト数ではなく文字数になっていました。その為、JSONが欠損しており Invalid JSON のエラーが出ていた模様です。
data=ujson.dumps(DataObj)

の部分を
data=ujson.dumps(DataObj.encode('utf-8'))

としたところ、Content-Lengthが正しいバイト数になりDiscordに日本語を含むDM（メッセージ）を送信できるようになりました。
